# Invalid API Key identifier specified aws api gateway boto3

Tags: python, aws-api-gateway, boto3

I tried to validate an api_key that i create on the console api gateway with boto3, and this is my code:

```
def apikey_validate(api_key):
    try:
        client = boto3.client('apigateway')
        response = client.get_api_key(
        apiKey=api_key,
        includeValue = False
        )
        return response
    except ClientError as e:
        return e.response
```

But the response is this:

```
"Error":{"Message":"Invalid API Key identifier specified","Code":"NotFoundException"},
"ResponseMetadata":{"RequestId":"d7dbf2c6-7bb6-4747-929a-ec737c8fadc7",
"HTTPStatusCode":404,
"HTTPHeaders":{"date":"Tue, 28 Apr 2020 23:40:04 GMT","content-type":"application/json",
"content-length":"51",
"connection":"keep-alive",
"x-amzn-requestid":"d7dbf2c6-7bb6-4747-929a-ec737c8fadc7","x-amzn-errortype":"NotFoundException","x-amz-apigw-id":"LuLBPKDbIAMEdrA="},
"RetryAttempts":0}}
```

And I can't understand what happens if is like the [documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/apigateway.html#APIGateway.Client.get_api_key) and the api_key is create resent

Comment: You `api_key` is the actually value of the key or its identifier. In should be the latter.

Comment: @Marcin is the real value

Comment: So you know what it errors out. You must provide key identifier, not a value.

Comment: @Marcin thanks and you Know how i validate the api_key value from boto3?

Comment: I don't know what you want to do. But to search keys by values you can use [get_api_keys](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/apigateway.html#APIGateway.Client.get_api_keys). But this is iterative process as you get all keys and search for the key value of intrest.

Comment: @Marci i need validate the api_key and token from request on lambda authorizer and the resuest header send me the apy_keyand token

Comment: API gateway will not allow any request with invalid api key. So I don't think you need to manually validate it. But if you want to do a reverse lookup (key value -> key id), then I'm not aware of an "easy" api call for that. I think either have to iterate over results of `get_api_keys` or keep this info (key value->key id) in some external db (e.g. dynamodb or elasticcache).

Answer (score 3):

Based on the comments, the error occurs because the [get_api_key](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/apigateway.html#APIGateway.Client.get_api_key) expects API key identifier, not the key's value:

> [Required] The **identifier** of the ApiKey resource.

Answer (score 0):

@Marcin I did this so as not to increase the computational complexity of the lambda.

```
effect= "Deny"
if result["user"]:
   effect="Allow"
policy = {
          "principalId": "user", 
          "policyDocument": {
            "Version": "2012-10-17",
            "Statement": [
              {
                "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
                "Effect": effect,
                "Resource": event["methodArn"]
              }
            ]
          },
          "usageIdentifierKey": result["apikey"]
        }
return policy
```